# PHP PDO show tables function shows only latest table not all

Tags: php, count, pdo, mysql

The following code is supposed to count the number of tables in the database. It only counts the latest table. As does my attempt to list the tables by name, only listing the latest. All the tables are just for testing and do not have any different attributes.

```
function checkdbempty(){
    global $fsdbh;
    $results = $fsdbh->query("show tables");
    foreach($results as $result); { $int += 1; }
    return $int;
}
```

That will return 1 result.

```
function checkdbempty(){
    global $fsdbh;
    $check = $fsdbh->query('show tables')->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach($check as $ch){ echo $ch; }
}
```

This will tell me the name of the first table:

```
function checkdbempty(){
    global $fsdbh;
    $check = $fsdbh->query('show tables')->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); $result = '';
    foreach($check as $ch){ $result.= $ch; }
    return $result;
}
```

And it will count only one with `->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);`

What is the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$sth = $fsdbh->prepare('show tables');
$sth->execute();
return $sth->rowCount();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($results as $result); { $int += 1; }
```

`foreach` is terminated by semicolon, the code after it is executed only once.

```
 $check = $fsdbh->query('show tables')->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

`$check` is single row fetched from statement, if you want to traverse every row use `fetchAll` method

Answer (score 1):

`fetch()` will fetch only one row, and is not used in method chaining so much.  You want to [`fetchAll()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) instead.  When you use `PDO::FETCH_NUM`, you are fetching the columns with numeric indices rather than column names in an associative array -- you are *not* retrieving the number of rows returned by the query

```
$check = $fsdbh->query('show tables')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
var_dump($check);
```

It is unwise to chain methods in this manner, even though `show tables` is known to be syntactically correct and should not fail in the RDBMS.  Instead, check for  a `FALSE` return then fetch:

```
$result = $fsdbh->query('show tables');
if ($result) {
  $check = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

Using `fetch()` for single rows assumes you will fetch inside a `while` loop:

```
$rows = array();
$results = $fsdbj->query('show tables');
if ($results){
  while ($row = $results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
  }
}
```